# Parallel Coordinate plot in plotly with continuous and categorical data

Tags: python, plot, plotly, parallel-coordinates

Let's say I have some dataframe `df` with continuous *and* categorical data. Now I'd like to make a parallel-coordinate plot in plotly that contains both types of coordinates. Is it possible to combine these into one plot such that each datapoint line goes through *all* axes?

In the documentation I did find `go.Parcoords` and `go.Parcats` that treat these separately, but I didn't find a way to combine them.
This is my minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
df = pd.DataFrame()
# continuous data
df['x1'] = [1,2,3,4]
df['x2'] = [9,8,7,6]
# categorical data
df['x3'] = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
df['x4'] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C']
col_list = [dict(range=(df[col].min(), df[col].max()),
                 label=col,
                 values=df[col])
            for col in df.keys()
            #if col not in ['x3', 'x4']  # only works if we exclude these (uncomment to run)
            ]
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Parcoords(dimensions=col_list))
fig.show()
```

Comment: Check this,  I hope you find it useful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64146570/18963373

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution based on customizing the tick names (`ticktext`). First we replace each categorical value with an integer, and then we define our custom ticks with the corresponding categorical value as a string:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x1'] = [1,2,3,4]
df['x2'] = [9,8,7,6]
df['x3'] = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
df['x4'] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C']
keys = df.keys()
categorical_columns = ['x3', 'x4']
col_list = []

for col in df.keys():
    if col in categorical_columns:  # categorical columns
        values = df[col].unique()
        value2dummy = dict(zip(values, range(len(values))))  # works if values are strings, otherwise we probably need to convert them
        df[col] = [value2dummy[v] for v in df[col]]
        col_dict = dict(
            label=col,
            tickvals=list(value2dummy.values()),
            ticktext=list(value2dummy.keys()),
            values=df[col],
        )
    else:  # continuous columns
        col_dict = dict(
            range=(df[col].min(), df[col].max()),
            label=col,
            values=df[col],
        )
    col_list.append(col_dict)
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Parcoords(dimensions=col_list))
fig.show()
```